Nex-Auth's signIn returns a string as a response and not the actual response
I'm using next-auth 5.0.0-beta.19 and next 14.2.4 (with app router).
I have a modal login component so that you can login from any unprotected route. This is my Next-Auth configuration and authorize works exactly as expected.


//auth.ts
export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,
  signIn,
  signOut,
} = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      //name
      //credentials
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const res = await api.get("api_endpoint", 
          { email: credentials.email,
            password: credentials.password
           });
          const user = {
            id: res.data.id,
            email: res.data.email,
            error: null,
          };
          return user;
        } catch (error) {
          const err = error as AxiosError;
          return {
            id: "",
            email: "",
            error: err.response?.data?.error,
          };
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/",
  },
  //callbacks
  })



This is how I set up my server action for login handling:


// actions/login.ts
import { signIn } from "@/auth";

export async function login(state: InitialState, formData: FormData) {
  const response = await signIn("credentials", {
    email: formData.get("email"),
    password: formData.get("password"),
    redirect: false,
  });
  console.log(response); // outputs http://localhost:3000/
  if (response.error) {
    //handle error
  }
  redirect("/home")
}



Instead of getting a response from login() I get a string containing the URL from where the login form was submitted. I suspect there is something wrong with the configuration of Next-Auth or the fact that I don't have a dedicated login route but I just can't find anything relevant to the problem online so any help is greatly appreciated.
